# CGContextRef inset?

Tags: ios, cgcontextref, insets

So, I have this code, that draws a circle with a line around it.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 40.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 132.0/255.0, 128.0/255.0, 128.0/255.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);
}
```

The problem is that half of the width of the line falls outside the rect.
So, what I would like to do, is to create an inset relative to the line width, to compensate for this. 
Or maybe there is a method, that tells my line to remain inside the boundaries of the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filling,

```
rect = CGRectInset(rect, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Now that was easy. I should do some more reading, I guess.
So, actually, the code would be 
float linewidth=40;
...
CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, linewidth);
...
rect = CGRectInset(rect, linewidth/2, linewidth/2);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, rect);